# Why does Prism syntax highlighter add a space in front of the CSS class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using Prism syntax highlighter from http://prismjs.com

If I do something like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="prism.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="prism.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>
            <code class="language-css">
p { color: blue }
            </code>
        </pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

I see the following result in my Chrome Dev Tools:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="prism.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="prism.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre class=" language-css">
            <code class=" language-css">
                <span class="token selector">p</span> <span class="token punctuation">{</span> <span class="token property">color</span><span class="token punctuation">:</span> blue <span class="token punctuation">}</span>
            </code>
        </pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

I know that Prism adds the `language-css` class to the `pre` tag. But where does the leading space (`" language-css"`) come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably just does `element.className += " language-css"` so that if the element already has a class on it (like `"foo"`), it ends up with `foo language-css` rather than `foolanguage-css`. Since the space is harmless, that was fairly common before `classList` support was good.

Comment: [This is (almost) exactly right](https://github.com/PrismJS/prism/blob/b8ce1e7ccf38f867c3011255633e075d16799297/components/prism-core.js#L191)

Comment: @lonesomeday: LOL Nice one! I was going to open with "You'd have to look at the Prism source, but..."